# Code not working after subscribe from a post method

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have a `service` that is using a `http` `post` `request` to the database. Whenever I use this in my `.ts` file nothing happens after I subscribe to the post. For example the post works but the `console.log` after does not even execute.

login.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { AuthService } from 'src/app/services/auth-services';
import { LoadingController } from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['login.page.scss']
})
export class HomePage implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    public authService: AuthService,
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    public loadingCtrl: LoadingController,

  ) {}

  email = '';
  pw = '';

  ngOnInit() {
  }


   login() {
      this.authService.login(this.email, this.pw).subscribe(result => {
      console.log('Valid User');
      this.navCtrl.navigateForward('/menu/first/');
      },  error => {
          if (error.status === 401) {
            console.log('Authorisation Required');
          }
        }
      );
  } 
}
```

service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import { NavController, AlertController } from '@ionic/angular';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

let apiUrl = 'http://ccoulter12.lampt.eeecs.qub.ac.uk/api/';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    public alertCtrl: AlertController,
    ) { }

login(emailin, pwin): Observable<any> {
    const data = {
      email: emailin,
      pw: pwin
    };
    return this.http.post<any>(apiUrl + 'login.php', JSON.stringify(data));
  }

}
```

Comment: You have added return statement in login method for the subscription. That won't work. Remove that return statement and check it again

Comment: Done. Still nothing

Comment: Please send the complete code, will check it and let you know

Comment: Thats the full code posted. Thank you I have been stuck for ages on this

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
login() {
  return this.authService.login(this.email, this.pw).subscribe({
    next(result) {
      this.presentLoading();
      // store jwt
      // move to dashboard
      console.log('Valid User');
      this.navCtrl.navigateForward('/menu/first/tabs/tab1');
    }, error(error) {
      if (error.status === 401) {
        console.log('Authorisation Required');
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Im getting an error that it cannot find the name next

Answer (score 0):

On controller you change login function to:

```
            login() {
                this.authService.login(this.email, this.pw);
              }
```

In AuthService, change login function to:

```
     apiUrl = 'http://ccoulter12.lampt.eeecs.qub.ac.uk/api/';

  login(emailin: string, pwin: string) {
    const data = {
      email: emailin,
      pw: pwin
    };
    this.http.post(this.apiUrl + 'login.php', JSON.stringify(data)).subscribe(result => {
      console.log('Valid User');
    }, error => {
      if (error.status === 401) {
        console.log('Authorisation Required');
      }
    }
    );
  }
```

In the component, inject service and call its method, while subscribe to the service directly in requesting. This solution works fine. Server return me 403 error.

If you pass the parameters to the method, specify the type, if you do not know, give 'any'